# Are there benefits to feeding my cat homemade chicken broth?

Tags: cats, feeding, diet

I make a homemade soup by bringing to the boil and then simmering a chicken. I do this without seasoning, then when the chicken is thoroughly cooled, I pull all the flesh from the bones and use this and the water as the base for the soup. I then add vegetables and salt.

If I don't use other seasoning, is it OK for my cat to drink the juice or broth from this mixture?

Should I only give it without salt and would the addition of freshly cooked vegetables affect the juice?

What are the benefits or drawbacks?

Comment: Well if the salt has no other nutritional purpose then you can definitely leave it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Some people have found homemade chicken broth (just boil the chicken in water, there is no need to add any vegetables, definitely not onions) very helpful for their CKD cats.
>   <sub>from [Tanya's Comprehensive Guide to feline chronic kidney disease](http://www.felinecrf.org/which_foods.htm#onion), which has some good information about chicken broth with good references.</sub>

I have also found that a cat will drink chicken broth if you find they are not drinking enough water. (easier to tell in an indoor cat)

Answer (score 3):

I've often found that giving my cats chicken broth when they seem to be getting a cold has either shortened the cold or prevented it altogether. Basically if the cat sneezes more than once they get a bowl of chicken broth (yes, usually low sodium is best).

Answer (score 0):

I boil chicken legs and thighs without the skin in regular water. I then make portions and freeze them and snack bags and give to my cats daily. I also simmer the bones a little bit longer for the broth with no additional ingredients and give it to two of my three cats. My black cat who was balding around her ears and her belly has grown all her hair back. And it also made her coat very shiny. She’s 12 and looks six.